# Spinning white dots on black background (no text) after Windows update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

About a year ago, my desktop machine died.  I hardly ever used it anymore due to a new laptop, so I didn't rush to fix it.  Today I finally did - a new PSU did the trick.  It booted into Windows 10 just fine, all good.

Obviously though, having not been booted in a year, there were a lot of updates to do.  Gulp.

Windows warned me thusly (I took a photo so I have it word for word):

```
Your PC is at risk - updating it now
-------------------------------------

Your PC is missing important updates including security fixes. We'll download them now, so please remember to:

* Keep your PC plugged in
* Keep it connected to the network
* Don't turn it off or close the lid

Downloading and installing the update might take an hour, but you can keep using this PC while we're working in the background.
```

Ok, no problem.  I left it alone, and when I came back half an hour later there was a message saying there had been some sort of error.  Sadly I didn't take a photo of this one.  It suggested I contact Windows technical support, quoting some hexadecimal error code. I clicked on the support link, AND IMMEDIATELY THE CODE DISAPPEARED.  WTF.  I'd been planning on copying and pasting that mofo, and hadn't made a note of it.

Windows support seemed kinda pointless at that point, so with trepidation I hit the windows key and clicked on the shutdown button.  Best option I had was "Update Windows and restart".  Gulp.  Here goes.

That seemed to go ok for a long time.  It spent a while downloading/installing bits, then briefly gave me the Windows logo, then downloaded/installed some more, then prompted me with a login screen.

I logged in, all fine.  On the desktop was now an icon for Windows Update Assistant (that wasn't there before).  I clicked it, and it started downloading some more and installing some more. Then it announced that it needed to do a restart.  I dutily clicked on the restart button... and now half an hour later I still have spinning white dots on a black background.

Is there any chance that it's doing something useful, and I should leave it alone, or is it time to try something?  And if so, what...?

Thank you!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the only things I have connected to the tower are power/hdmi/ethernet/usb keyboard/lusb ogitech wireless mouse receiver

Comment: Turns out I have the patience of whatever the opposite of a saint is.  In the absence of any immediate help here, I held the power button until it turned off.  Now it's doing some more updates, it was on 75% when it first came up, up to 81% now.  Fingers crossed.  I unplugged the USB wireless receiver just because I've learnt over the years to unplug ANYTHING that isn't essential when something goes wrong - I doubt it made a difference, but who knows.

Comment: "Is there any chance that it's doing something useful" - Yes;  You are installing the whichever feature was downloaded.

Comment: With no text on the screen, not even a Windows logo?  Pretty poor user experience if so!